# Override user agent (Chrome) default styles inside GWT

Tags: css, google-chrome, gwt

i've a TabBar that after the last Chrome upgrade (32.0.1700.76 m) is displayed with an outline on focused tabs:
[image: outlined tab]

In past version there wasn't. To restore old view i tried to set some outline in CSS, like this:

```
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem:focus {
outline: lime auto 5px !important;
}
```

(lime is just for see if it works).

Even this edit, the computed style still remains the default (`-webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;`
):
[image: computed style]

What should i do to override this user agent style?

**EDIT**

I think the blue outline is not of the HTML (div):

[image: label outline]

[image: label code]

[image: label modifier]

[image: label outline css]

The one i want to put away is on the TabBar Item object:

[image: tabbatitem outline]

[image: tabbatitem code]

[image: tabbaritem modifier]

[image: tabbaritem outline css]

I honestly don't know why the Churro solution worked before :(

Comment: Do you have a site where we can see the complete code?

Comment: No, sorry. The project is not yet ready to be published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following CSS to highlight the textarea on this Stackoverflow page, and it worked:

```css
.wmd-input:focus {
    outline: lime auto 5px !important;
}
```

Make sure your selector in front of `:focus` is correct.

**EDIT**

I took a look at a TabPanel in my own GWT app. The element that gets a blue ring around it in a TabBarItem is the `Label` (div) containing the tab's text, not the `gwt-TabBarItem`.

**Try this selector**: `.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected .gwt-Label:focus`

Comment: Your selector `.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected .gwt-Label:focus` works (also without `!important` token), thank you!

Comment: @Fuzzo Did you change something that caused it to not work anymore? My code works for any GWT tab panel, including the one in my app. Can you deploy your app somewhere and let me see? You can also try targeting both the TabItem and the TabItem Label like this: `.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected .gwt-Label:focus, .gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected:focus { ...`

Comment: You were always right! Due to my error in css refactor i lost the initial `.gwt-TabBar` token. Now it works! Thanks a lot again!